# Boundary fill algorithm stops filling halfway

Tags: c, bgi, turbo-c

I'm trying to implement the simple boundary fill method (using 4 connected approach) for filling a rectangle. I did it as follows (code below), but the rectangle is not getting filled properly: it stops filling when it reaches the half portion of the rectangle.

But the same code works fine when trying to fill a circle. Can anyone help me to figure out the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <graphics.h>

void boundfill(int xc, int yc, int r, int b) {
    int cur;
    cur = getpixel(xc, yc);
    if (cur != b && cur != r) {
        putpixel(xc, yc, r);
        delay(1);

        boundfill(xc + 1, yc, r, b);
        boundfill(xc - 1, yc, r, b);
        boundfill(xc, yc + 1, r, b);
        boundfill(xc, yc - 1, r, b);
    }
}

void main() {
    int gd = DETECT, gm;
    initgraph(&gd, &gm, "..\\bgi");

    rectangle(100, 100, 300, 300);
    boundfill(105, 105, 4, WHITE);

    getch();
    closegraph();
}
```

Output:

[image: Output 1]

But when I use the following co-ordinates for rectangle, it is working fine. Given co-ordinates:

```
rectangle(50, 50, 100 ,100);
boundfill(55, 55, 4, WHITE);
```

For this the output is:

[image: Output 2]

Comment: I don't think you've given us quite enough context.  It looks as though the code you show is supposed to fill a rectangle which has a boundary in colour `b` and other data that has to be in colour `r` at the end.  The only constraint on the recursive calls is that boundary; otherwise, the code will merrily go outside the bounds of the rectangle with the ±1 operations.  Presumably, your `rectangle()` function marks the boundary of the rectangle with WHITE — if it doesn't, your code is hosed.  Is this the signature for `rectangle()`: `void rectangle(int ll_x, int ll_y, int x_len, int y_len);`?

Comment: Rectangle function  : rectangle(int topleft_x,int topleft_y,int bottomright_x, int bottomright_y). In this code, I'm trying to fill a rectangle with GREEN fill color whose border color is WHITE(since default color is WHITE). For the time being, this is all I need in this code. I was just doing a sample with these colors

Comment: You're still providing minimal information — it doesn't help your cause. Add it to the question! Presumably, `initgraph()` creates a drawing area at least 350x250 units big. What colour is that drawing area? The `rectangle()` call creates a square 100x100; what's the colour of the body of that square at the start, and what's the colour of the boundary of that square at the start? How did the `rectangle()` call know to use those colours (it isn't obvious from the code)? Is your trouble simply the `delay(1)` in the tail of the `boundfill()`? That delay will occur each time the function returns?

Comment: @hyde I've just included the output images. Kindly go through it. Also, it is sure that default border colour is WHITE

Comment: Do you get an error message when "it stops filling"? Something like, "a stack overflow occured" perhaps?

Comment: @JeNy Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill for ideas on how to fix this.

Comment: @hyde I tried the code using 8 connected approach too. Still its not working. If you have an idea regarding such situations where these algorithms don't work, can you please tell me the possible reason why its not working?

Comment: @Jongware No error messages are displayed

Comment: @JeNy You run out of stack space. Without going to details, only real solutions are: with the same algorithm, replace recursion with iteration and your own "stack" data structure, or switch the algorithm so it does not do so deep recursion.

Comment: @JeNy: so far you are *nowhere* telling what actually happens. Yes, it stops filling -- we got that, and it's your main problem. But what does "it stops filling" **mean**? Does the program stop? Does it continue? Does your computer start to smoke?

Answer (score 1):

What platform are you using?

- is this 32 or 16 bit executable?

BGI is very old Borland gfx API still used for learning purposes if it is original Borland BGI then you are creating 16bit DOS app. There are also wrappers/emulators of BGI for Windows and Linux in that case it depend on your compiler settings.

What can be wrong:

1. **heap/stack**

   in 16bit DOS mode you can see just first 1 MB of memory space from which is 640KB available for whole system. In your program/project/compiler settings there are additional constraints like initial/maximum heap and stack size for your app. If set too low then you can have heap stack problems in that case it should throw an exception but in my experience I see a lot stranger things then missing exceptions.

   When you filling 100x100 pixel area you are recursing up to 10000 times and your recursion call (16bit case) contains:

   ```
   1 x return address segment+offset = 4 Byte
   4 x int16 operand = 8 Byte
   1 x int local variable = 2 Byte
   ```

   all together 14 Byte (on some C/C++ engines truncated to 16 Bytes) not counting additional data need for subcalls like putpixel ... Multiply it by recursion count and you are well above safety for sure on 16 bit DOS. To check this:

   - the filling should stop on the same spot each time (if no more processing is in your code)
   - if you add some variables into function header it should stop sooner then before
   - change of heap/stack limit should affect this also

   to repair this eliminate all unnecessary tings from recursion for example `b,r` are constant so they can be in global variable. If you set `xc,yc` back to original state before return then you can use `&xc,&yc`. Your cur local variable can be static. This will eliminate all allocations in your recursion only the return address remain.
2. **gfx mode**

   BGI is mostly used for 16 color modes on higher resolutions you are crossing 64KB barriers. If there is something wrong with your BGI driver it could hang up or stop drawing. In that case the stop will occur on the same place no matter the bullet **#1**. To avoid this change BGI driver, use different resolution or better emulator

Answer (score 1):

Without additional information - this smells just like a stack overflow. My assumption is based on the following:

1. Your algorithm is excessively recursive.
2. The problem arises for a larger rectangle
3. The filling pattern you provided in consistent with the assumption that your program just preliminary "stopped" (crashed actually). That is, your recursion path is filling horizontally first, and then vertically.

Taking the discussion of the effectiveness of this specific filling algorithm aside, note that using recursive algorithms in general is justified only when the recursion depth has reasonable limitation.

For example, using recursion on balanced binary trees is ok, since such a tree depth (and hence recursion depth) grows logarithmically with the tree size. On the other hand using recursion for linked list operation isn't justified.

If you insist on using this specific algorithm, I believe you should get rid of recursion. You may put your starting point in a queue, and then in a loop pop a point from the queue, paint, and push its neighbors into the queue. Similar to BFS algorithm.

Comment: This post doesn't look like an attempt to answer this question. Every post here is expected to be an explicit attempt to *answer* this question; if you have a critique or need a clarification of the question or another answer, you can [post a comment](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) (like this one) directly below it. Please remove this answer and create either a comment or a new question. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)